# Is the value Vm correct in a FM modulation?

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation

Recently I calculated the Vm and the Vc.
However I think the value is ackward and strange.

This is the scope image:
[image]

With the information:
[image]

This is what I have done:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems right to me , at least the shape
I can’t say much about the value though because I don’t know the details of this case

Answer (score 0):

wrong --> Looks like your frequency varies from 3KHz to about 1.5KHertz.

Variation is 3 cycles per division, to 1.5 cycles per division, at 500uSec per
division, thus 6KHz to 3KHz.

wrong -->The deltaF is 1,500 Hertz, suggesting 15 volts is the modulation input.

The correct deltaF is 3,000Hz, which at 100 Hertz/volt suggests 30 volts is the peak-peak modulation input.

Comment: Can we calculate it like this: f=cycles/time = 25/5*10^-3 = 5000Hz then the Baseband = 5kHz   ...   Because I do not see the 3Khz and 1500Hz